# Using a sub to call an array within a function

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I have a little problem with my sub. This sub is calling to different functions, by using the sub's data. The first function finds one is finding the amount of unique values and the second function finds these values. However, the first function works fine because its output is a scalar value. However, the second function's output is an array. I have tried to search for a solution, but so far I have not succeeded. I have a theory that the issue has something to do with the `ByRef A() As Integer`. I have written the codes below, both for the sub and the second function.

```
Sub Test()
Dim A() As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim BB As Integer
n = 10
ReDim A(n, 2) '5 unikke

A(1, 1) = 1
A(2, 1) = 7
A(3, 1) = 2
A(4, 1) = 6
A(5, 1) = 3
A(6, 1) = 5
A(7, 1) = 1
A(8, 1) = 1
A(9, 1) = 1
A(10, 1) = 4

A(1, 2) = 1
A(2, 2) = 7
A(3, 2) = 2
A(4, 2) = 6
A(5, 2) = 3
A(6, 2) = 5
A(7, 2) = 1
A(8, 2) = 1
A(9, 2) = 1
A(10, 2) = 4

BB = Unikke(A) 'Unikke is the second function that provides the amount of unique values
Dim FF() As Integer
ReDim FF(BB, 1)

FF = HvilkeUnikke(A) 'the second function, which has the output of an array a.k.a the problem

End Sub
```

This is the function:

```
Public Function HvilkeUnikke(ByRef A() As Integer) As Integer

Dim L() As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim A2() As String
Dim BB As Integer
Dim C() As Integer

BB = Unikke(A)

ReDim C(UBound(A), 2)
ReDim A2(BB, 1)
ReDim L(BB, 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(A)
    C(i, 1) = A(i, 1)
    C(i, 2) = A(i, 2)
Next

For i = 1 To UBound(C)
B = 0
    For i2 = 1 To UBound(C)
        If C(i, 1) = C(i2, 2) Then
            B = B + 1
            If B > 1 Then
                C(i2, 2) = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i2
Next i

B = 0
For i2 = 1 To UBound(C)
    If C(i2, 2) > 0 Then
        B = B + 1
        L(B, 1) = C(i2, 2)

    End If
Next i2


HvilkeUnikke = L
End Function
```

The results are as expected, but they should be in a variable inside my sub.

Comment: You have dimensioned `FF` as an Integer Array `Dim FF() As Integer` but then the function you try to populate it with only returns one single integer `Public Function HvilkeUnikke(ByRef A() As Integer) As Integer` - even though you try to set its value as an array of integers again using `HvilkeUnikke = L` where L is int array `L()`

Comment: Bascally, could you try putting `()` at the end of the function declaration/signature; change `Public Function HvilkeUnikke(ByRef A() As Integer) As Integer` to `Public Function HvilkeUnikke(ByRef A() As Integer) As Integer()`

Comment: That is correct, there was also a problem with the variable `L` and it is solved by now. However, the second comment was very helpful. Now it works, and I will update the code above for others who need help. Thank you!

Comment: Good work and good luck!

Comment: You shouldn't answer your question in your question. You should write up an answer, it's perfectly fine to write your own answer to your question if @jamheadart doesn't want to

Comment: Yeah you should write an official answer @MathiasEriksen and then accept it for some points and an upvote :D

Comment: Ahhhh I will  do that. Thank you for remind me :)

Answer (score 1):

(The solution)

```
Sub test()

Dim FF() As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim A() As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim BB As Integer
n = 10
ReDim A(n, 2) '7 unikke

A(1, 1) = 1
A(2, 1) = 7
A(3, 1) = 2
A(4, 1) = 6
A(5, 1) = 3
A(6, 1) = 5
A(7, 1) = 1
A(8, 1) = 1
A(9, 1) = 1
A(10, 1) = 4

A(1, 2) = 1
A(2, 2) = 7
A(3, 2) = 2
A(4, 2) = 6
A(5, 2) = 3
A(6, 2) = 5
A(7, 2) = 1
A(8, 2) = 1
A(9, 2) = 1
A(10, 2) = 4


BB = Unikke(A)

ReDim FF(BB)

FF = HvilkeUnikke(A)

'Testing on the worksheet
For i = 1 To BB
    Cells(i, 1) = FF(i)
Next


End Sub
```

And the function

```
Public Function HvilkeUnikke(ByRef A() As Integer) As Integer()

Dim L() As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim A2() As String
Dim BB As Integer
Dim C() As Integer

BB = Unikke(A)

ReDim C(UBound(A), 2)
ReDim A2(BB, 1)
ReDim L(BB)

For i = 1 To UBound(A)
    C(i, 1) = A(i, 1)
    C(i, 2) = A(i, 2)
Next

For i = 1 To UBound(C)
B = 0
    For i2 = 1 To UBound(C)
        If C(i, 1) = C(i2, 2) Then
            B = B + 1
            If B > 1 Then
                C(i2, 2) = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i2
Next i

B = 0
For i2 = 1 To UBound(C)
    If C(i2, 2) > 0 Then
        B = B + 1
        L(B) = C(i2, 2)
    End If
Next i2


HvilkeUnikke = L

End Function
```